# Get different column value from same table laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have table "results" :

```
id_kriteria id_compare  grade
    1       1           10
    1       2           40
    2       1           50
    2       2           20
```

and I have table "kriterias" where id_kriteria and id_compare has the same name :

```
id_kriteria kriteria_name
    1       Item A
    2       Item B
```

How to do the select in laravel (if possible in eloquent) so that I can get result like this :

```
Kriteria ID     Compare ID  Grade
    ItemA       ItemA       10
    ItemA       ItemB       40
    ItemB       ItemA       50
    ItemB       ItemB       20
```

when doing foreach in view ?

I did have "hasmany" relation in Kriterias Model.

**EDIT**

```
$r1s = Result::join('kriterias', 'kriterias.id_kriteria', '=', 'results.id_compare')
            //join('kriterias','kriterias.id_kriteria', '=', 'results.id_kriteria' )
            ->orderBy('kriterias.id_kriteria')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Simplest `INNER JOIN` scenario.

Comment: it's not working, I get kriteria ID name sequence in Compare ID column.

Comment: Please share your query.

Comment: update question if i use join twice i get sql error